# Remembering the user after signing in with Google API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

I need help with signing in using the Google API. I have the button **sign-in with Google** on my website by using their API:

```
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript';
    po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
})();)
```

However, when I refresh the page, or go to another page, It shows me the sign-in button and I need to sign-in again.

How can I "remember" the user after the first login, even after refreshing the page?

With Facebook, it's easy, just using:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(updateStatusCallback));
```

Thanks!

Comment: May be use cookie to store the status?